# Facebook users posts/feed not showing , using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, api, facebook-graph-api, salesforce, apex

I am using `Facebook Graph API` in `Salesforce` and using user search fetching all the users .

On clicking or selecting one of the particular user , the posts/feeds of that user/profile didnt coming up.

I am making an HTTP GET request with endpoint URL as :

```
**endpointurl=**'https://graph.facebook.com/'+searchtxtfblocal+'?fields=id,name,location,picture,education,birthday,link,first_name,last_name,statuses.limit(20).fields(message,id,updated_time),photos.limit(20).type(uploaded).fields(id,link,picture,source,updated_time,name,created_time,width,icon,height),videos.limit(20).type(uploaded).fields(id,source,picture,created_time,embed_html,name,updated_time,description),links.limit(20).fields(created_time,description,link,id,name,message,picture,icon)&access_token='+facebooklogindetailxml.AccessToken;
```

where `searchtxtfblocal` is `user/profile id`.

Now certain parameters of this endpoint are coming `Null` like `statuses`,`username`,`birthday`,`links`,`likes`,`photos`,etc in the debug .

I have valid access token, still getting these parameters null.

Can you please suggest a way to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

These must have to do with permission scopes, and you haven't specified the querying user. If the querying user `me` (meaning the access token belongs to the person who you're querying for), you require corresponding permission scopes, for example;

> `statuses` & `links` require `read_stream` or `user_posts` 
>   `birthday` requires `user_birthday` 
>  `likes` requires `user_likes`
>   
>  `photos` requires `user_photos`

If you're querying for some other user, you can only retrieve public feeds.

`username` is deprecated, and doesn't work anymore.